# How to add the hex values of two or more chars?

Tags: c++, char, hex

I am storing some hex values inside a char array. I would like to sum these hex values and if it is bigger than 1 byte then it should drop the larger bits.

For example I might declare
char a = 0x21;
char b = 0x07;

and so I would like to add them to  get a hex value of 0x28 as it should be, which is stored as a char.

Comment: `char c = a + b;`?

Comment: Sounds like you may want to be using `unsigned char`. They can easily represent values from `0x00` to `0xFF` and have implicit modulo arithmetic ("dropping off" the largest bits).

Comment: Just to clarify a misunderstanding you might have, you cannot *store* hex values in a char. A char is just a small integer. All you can do is print that small integer as hex or decimal or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks tkausl. It made me realise the answer will be in int type, and I was confused why it gave me 40.

I was looking for char(a+b).

Comment: 40 is the correct answer. Obviously 40 is the same number as 0x28. You seem to have a misunderstanding that numbers are stored in hex or decimal. They aren't, they're only printed as hex or decimal. You can print an `int` as hex and you can print a `char` as decimal if you want.